# Hyper-V and CPU Usage

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, performance, hyper-v

I'm renting VPS that I believe is using `Hyper-V`. Lately the processor performance of my VPS has been terrible, yet the CPU usage in the task manager doesn't show it struggling. Is the CPU usage in the task manager not a useful measurement in a `Hyper-V` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CPU usage as shown in Task Manager running as a Hyper-V VM is not all that useful.

You need to be able to take measurements from the hypervisor in order to get an idea of what the load on the actual hardware is.

This is a common problem in virtualized environments. You have "noisy neighbors," i.e. other people with VMs that are competing for the same physical resources as you.

This is why many cloud providers offer "dedicated" resources for a premium, so that you don't have to worry about the aforementioned problem.